# Как делать короткие ссылки

Tags: ссылки

Здравствуйте. Не могли бы вы подробно, насколько это возможно, написать, как делать короткие ссылки. Т.е. вместо длинных, ненужных латинских букв можно было вставить одно короткое слово. Напр: слово "здесь".Чтобы можно было на него нажать и открылась ссылка. В интернете есть множества статей, но , увы, я ничего не понял из них. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `create table short_url( id int unsigned auto_increment primary key, url varchar(255) );`

Получение котроткой ссылки по длинной:

2a) `intert into short_url ( url ) values ( длинная_ссылка );`

2b) которкая ссылка = `http://домен_сервиса/ID`, где ID - id вставленной на этапе 2 записи

Переход по ссылке вида `http://домен_сервиса/ID`:

3a) `select url from short_url where id = ID`, где ID достаётся из ссылки

3b) перенаправление клиента по URL, который получили на этапе 3a

Всё. Детали реализации на личное усмотрение.